# Right Shift in C++ giving unusual results (unsigned 64-bit)

Tags: c++, binary-operators

I am in the horrible world of bit shifting. I have the following code:

I am shifting this number: 140638023551944 >> 5.

The binary representation for 140638023551944 according to http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter is

1000011000011111011101000111

Right shifted 5, I expect: 0000010000110000111110111010

But instead, I get 4394938235998, which is 111111111101000110101110110111110001011110.

That number, to me, looks to have almost nothing at all to do with the original number. I don't see a pattern in one that exists in the other. It is very bizarre.

The code is along the lines of:

```
uint64_t n, index, tag;
uint64_t one = 1;
uint64_t address = 140638023551944;
/*left shift to get index into the last index.length() number of slots*/               
cout << "original address is " << address << " " << "\n";
n = (address >> 5);
cout << "after right shifting away offset bits " << n << "\n";
```

"address" is populated with the correct integer, 140638023551944. I have verified that.

What is this bizarre behavior? It is consistent with this simulator: http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=10&number=140638023551944&place=5&operator=Shift+Right! But I am pretty sure right shift is not supposed to work that way!

Comment: What type is `address`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson it, too, is uint64_t.

Comment: Your decimal to binary conversion is incorrect. A 28 bit binary number is certainly not sufficient to hold the same value as a 15 digit decimal number.

Comment: Your "reference" does indeed seem to be wrong, since my calculator gives 4.394938236×10¹² as the answer for 140638023551944 / 32. In other words, your C++ code comes up with the RIGHT answer.

Comment: That looks about right. The dodgy site you're using to get the binary number doesn't cope with 64-bit values - it says "max. value of 4294967295".

Comment: Ah... let this be a cautionary tale against free Internet tools with no verified correctness.

Comment: I really see no fault in the website. It very clearly says the max allowable value above the input box

Comment: A basic guide is that 1 digit in decimal number is 3.3 bits, so you could do the math to come up with that answer. Or simply print the number yourself?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Indeed, it does say that. It's my own selective blindness that caused some failure, her. Glad to see that the output from the code is working as intended!

Comment: There appear to be nothing wrong in the actual code.

Comment: Strangely, your conversion of 4394938235998 to binary is correct, afaict. However, that number too is out of the range of the website. Out of curiousity, how did you do that conversion?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That is the output I got from my C++ code, I was debugging painfully, and in a craze I did it by hand, hah. Ends up I should have just done it by hand all along and I wouldn't have run into an issue in the first place.

Comment: [See it working](http://ideone.com/4NrVk2)

Answer (score 0):

```
// EVERYTHING WORKS CORRECTLY!

#include <cassert>   // assert()
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <cstdint>   // UINT64_MAX

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t n, index, tag;
    uint64_t one = 1;
    uint64_t address = 140638023551944;
    /*left shift to get index into the last index.length() number of slots*/
    cout << "original address is " << address << " " << "\n";
    n = (address >> 5);
    cout << "after right shifting away offset bits " << n << "\n";

    {   // Everything works correctly!
        assert( 140638023551944>>5 == 140638023551944/32 );
        assert( 140638023551944>>5 == 4394938235998 );

        assert( 140638023551944/32 == 4394938235998 );
        assert( 140638023551944 < UINT64_MAX );
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in OP works just fine. Flagged to close question as typo/no longer reproducible: see comments on OP.